# How can I edit Shark configurations on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, shark

The default shark 'Time Profile' configuration on the iPhone appears to sample every 1 ms.  I'd like to tweak it to sample every 100us.  I know this is possible to do on my local machine by editing the shark configurations, but I don't see a way to edit the configurations on the phone.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Answer: it would appear that you can't.

From the [Shark User Manual](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/SharkUserGuide/AdvancedHardwareCounterConfiguration/AdvancedHardwareCounterConfiguration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005233-CH10-SW30):

> Important: Currently, while you can
>   make custom ARM counter configurations
>   with Shark, there is no way to load
>   customized configuration files onto
>   your iPhone OS device using the iPhone
>   OS SDK. This restriction may be
>   relaxed in future versions of the SDK.
>   In the meantime, send suggestions for
>   useful configurations to
>   perftools-feedback@group.apple.com and
>   we may include them in future iPhone
>   OS SDK releases.